# Alternative to SimpleXML to use in commercial apps?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I need an XML parser like SimpleXML, to use in commercial apps.

I think SimpleXML can't be used in commercial apps. So, I'm searching here and on Google but couldn't find an alternative. The only easy-to-use and efficient parser I find is SimpleXML.

How do I go about using this on a commercial application?

Comment: Android provides at least two XML parsers: a Pull parser and a SAX parser. I think there's also a DOM parser as well.

Comment: they doesn't works like SimpleXML, you must implement the parser functions. I'm searching for something like SimpleXML that does all the work. It is a must for enormous XML files

Comment: But SimpleXML is PHP, isn't it?

Comment: It's under an apache license, no?

Comment: Smith, i'm talking about Android SimpeXML library. Dave, i'm not sure about the license, but if  it is apache i can't use it, because it is a commercial app (vs €'s) for a client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Apache licensed software in you Application, provided you include a copy of the license and give proper attribution. For more information read [this post](http://www.inteist.com/2010/05/how-to-use-apache-2-0-in-commercial-products-explained-in-simple-terms/) or read the [Apache 2.0 license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html).

PS: I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice. Read the license and seek a lawyer if you are unsure of anything mentioned in the license.